# How do I copy data from one Excel sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I need VB code for copying daata from one Excel sheet (sheet1) to another (sheet2). How do I do this?

Comment: You should not expect to be "Spoon fed". If you don't have required knowledge to do it there is always an option of recodring the macro and analysing/learning from auto generated code. There are numerous forums/web pages which gives sample code you are looking for. Even after doing your homework, if you face some problem raise it here. Don't expect a free lunch!!

Answer (score 2):

This will copy everything from the first worksheet to the second:

```
Sub Test()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```